# Rails 4 + enum: How to upcase the values in a collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have a model that uses enum:

```
class ScheduledPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { pending: 0, received: 1 }

  monetize :amount_cents
  belongs_to :lease

  scope :recent, -> { where(start_date: 30.days.ago..0.days.ago).order("start_date DESC") }
end
```

and a form for selecting one of the statuses:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @scheduled_payment] do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.collection_select :status, ScheduledPayment.statuses, :last, :first %>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

However, this creates a select dropdown with `pending` and `received`. How would I titlecase the values?

Comment: you can map the statuses: ScheduledPayment.statuses.map(&:titleize)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @scheduled_payment] do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.collection_select :status, ScheduledPayment.statuses.keys, :to_s, :titlecase %>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

You can't use the hash. It'll say that the value `'1'` is invalid. You have to set it to the string value.